# Leaflet.js & Mapbox.js - Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on'

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

I'm using Mapbox, which is based on Leaflet.js to generate my maps. I'm trying to add a layer group to my map. But every time I call .addTo(map), I get

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on'
```

My code is as follows:

```
map = L.mapbox.map("map", "dannyvaughton.map-lmwtrr8k").setView([54.4, 0.43], 14)
markers = new L.LayerGroup().addTo(map)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your version of MapBox.js to 1.0.4 - this is a bug that is fixed in the update.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
markers = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);
```

notice the lower camel case on layerGroup

You can't call .addTo on an object that isn't instantiated yet, you're alternative would be:

```
markers = new L.LayerGroup();
markers.addTo(map);
```

http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#layergroup